# How to combine exec commands in shell script

Tags: postgresql, bash, exec

I am running postgreSQL on docker.
In order to access the container I run

```
winpty docker exec -it postgres_db bash
```

Now that I am inside the docker container, I run this to access as user 'postgres' in postgres server

```
psql -U postgres
```

Then what I want to do is create a database

```
create database test;
```

I can I do this sequentially in a script?
I want something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
winpty docker run -p 8005:5432 --name postgres_db -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -d postgres
sleep 5
winpty docker exec -it postgres_db bash -c "psql -U postgres" [-c "create database test;"]
```

create database cannot be executed if im not inside "psql -U postgres". Obviously the last line **-c "create database test;"** is wrong, just to make you understand what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
winpty docker exec -it postgres_db bash -c "psql -U postgres -c 'CREATE DATABASE test;'"
```

Both `bash -c` and `psql -c` take one shell word as input. A single or double quoted string is one word. You need to nest the quotes, just like the `-c` commands are nested.

Alternative:

```
winpty docker exec -it postgres_db bash -c "psql -U postgres -c \"CREATE DATABASE test;\""
```